# group by dataframe to a desired format on a specific column

Tags: apache-spark

i have a dataframe in spark

```
+------+----------+
|sno   | ssn     |
+------+----------+
|   123|200000000|         
|   789|200000002|         
|   123|200000000|         
|   123|200000001|         
|   894|200000001|          
+------+----------+
```

i wanted to group by sno and when i group by serial number the resulting dataframe should be

```
+------+----------+---------
|sno   | ssn               |
+------+----------+---------
|   123|200000000,200000001|         
|   789|200000002          |         
|   894|200000001          |          
+------+----------+--------|
```

I am new to spark and how would i do this

when i register the table as temp table and do a sql group by i couldn't get the results in above format , how do i get the results?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [collect_set](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_set(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) after grouping by sno. Below is the code for the same.

```
//Creating Test Data
val df = Seq((123, 200000000), (789, 200000002), (123, 200000000), (123, 200000001), (894, 200000001))
  .toDF("sno", "ssn")

val df1 = df.groupBy("sno")
    .agg(collect_set("ssn").as("ssn"))

df1.show(false)

+---+----------------------+
|sno|ssn                   |
+---+----------------------+
|123|[200000000, 200000001]|
|789|[200000002]           |
|894|[200000001]           |
+---+----------------------+
```